# How To Add Comma Separators in React Native Text Input

Tags: react-native, formik, textinput, react-native-paper, currency-formatting

I am working on a React Native app. I am using [Formik](https://formik.org/) for my forms. And now my requirement is I have a **TextInput** where the user will type a price. This input field should add comma separators for **1000s** for example if I type **10000** the input field should show as **10,000** and if I type **100000** it should show as **100,000**. How to do that. FYI my **TextInput** is imported from [React Native Paper](https://reactnativepaper.com/)

Below is my code:

```
 <TextInput
  style={{ width: "auto", marginBottom: 10 }}
  mode="outlined"
  label="Starting Price"
  placeholder="25,000"
  inputMode="numeric"
  defaultValue="0"
  left={<TextInput.Affix text="LKR" />}
  onChangeText={obj.handleChange("startingPrice")}
  value={obj.values.startingPrice}
   />
```

Comment: do you need the comma just before the last 3 digits or at every 3 digit running in reverse, like if you have 123456789--> A.) 123,456,789 or B.)123456,789.
Which one do you need A.) or B.)

Comment: At every 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

You have an handleChange function. You can use this code in your function.

This is an example

```
const number = 100000;
const commaNumber = number.toLocaleString();
```

Output is: 100,000

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but sadly it is not working.

Comment: Could you please share the code you used?

Comment: `onChangeText={(value) => {const number = Number(value);const formattedNumber = number.toLocaleString();obj.setFieldValue("startingPrice", formattedNumber);}}value={obj.values.startingPrice}`

Answer (score 0):

Format a price string before showing it in `TextInput` and remove formatting before storing it. Something like this:

```
const [price, setPrice] = React.useState('');

<TextInput
...
  inputMode="numeric"
  onChangeText={(value) => setPrice(value.replaceAll(',', ''))}
  value={Number(price).toLocaleString()}
/>
```

Comment: This is working fine with normal state as you have done above. But its not working with [Formik](https://formik.org/)

Comment: It doesn't matter where a value is stored the same principle works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example. That can help you.

The `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` method is used to format a number into a string representation according to the specified locale and formatting options. This method provides a way to automatically format numbers based on the user’s locale, including adding commas for thousands separation and specifying decimal points.

```js
const number = 1234567.89;

// Using default formatting (based on user's locale)
const formattedNumberDefault = number.toLocaleString();
console.log(formattedNumberDefault); // Output depends on user's locale

// Specifying a specific locale (e.g., en-US)
const formattedNumberUS = number.toLocaleString('en-US');
console.log(formattedNumberUS); // Output: "1,234,567.89"

// Specifying options for formatting
const options = {
  style: 'decimal',  // Other options: 'currency', 'percent', etc.
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
};
const formattedWithOptions = number.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
console.log(formattedWithOptions); // Output: "1,234,567.89"
```

This method also handles scientific notation numbers, commonly known as exponential notation, which are represented using the format `x * 10^y`, where `x` is a coefficient and `y` is the exponent.

```js
const scientificNumber = 1.234e6; // 1.234 * 10^6 = 1234000

// Using default formatting (based on user's locale)
const formattedScientificDefault = scientificNumber.toLocaleString();
console.log(formattedScientificDefault); // Output depends on user's locale

// Specifying a specific locale (e.g., en-US)
const formattedScientificUS = scientificNumber.toLocaleString('en-US');
console.log(formattedScientificUS); // Output: "1,234,000"
```